# Is there a jQuery method to hide/show elements beside .hide()/.show()?

Tags: jquery

Is there a jQuery method to hide/show elements beside `.hide()`/`.show()`?

Currently I use:

```
function showMenu($theMenu) {

    $theMenu.css("left", "auto");
        
    return $theMenu;   // for chaining
    
}

function hideMenu($theMenu) {
    
    $theMenu.css("left", "-99999px");
    
    return $theMenu;   // for chaining

}
```

I would prefer to use a built-in jQuery method because I can then use:

```
$theMenu.show();
```

But, the built-in method uses `display: auto, none` which inhibits screen readers.

Appreciate it.

=====

**EDIT:**

I have decided to try to override the built-in jQuery methods, `show()` + `hide()`. For example,

```
$.fn.show = function() {

    this.each(function() {
        $(this).css("z-index", "100");
        $(this).css("left"   , "auto");
    });
    
    return this;
    
}
```

The above works, but this does not:

**WHY**?

```
$.fn.show = function() {

    this.each(function() {
    
        $(this).css({
            "z-index": "100",
            "left"   : "auto";
        });
    
    });
    
    return this;
    
}
```

Again, thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

You can try an alternative to `hide()` and `show()` functions

```js
function hideMenu($theMenu) {
    
    $theMenu.css('visibility', 'visible');;
    
    return $theMenu; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives:

```
.fadeOut();
.fadeIn();
.css('opacity', '0.0');
.css('opacity', '1.0');
.css('visibility', 'visible');
.css('visibility', 'hidden');
```